# Font appears jagged/pixelated after child mashes keyboard

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, fonts

the screenshots below are from Chrome 37 before and after my little boy mashed my keyboard. He definitely hit the Ctrl key and some other characters in the bottom-left hand area on the keyboard. Any idea what he did and how I can reverse it?

**Before**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]

**Settings > Advanced > Web Content**

[image: Web Content Settings]

**Settings > Advanced > Web Content > Customize Fonts**

[image: Customize Fonts Settings]

Comment: What does it say in settings - advanced - web content? Also in the customized font area?

Comment: Added screenshots of the requested settings.

Comment: What if you open it in safe mode?

Comment: Running in incognito mode, it looks fine.

Comment: If you don't have add-ons enabled in incognito, start disabling them one by one until it fixes in regular

Answer (score 0):

Chrome eventually crashed and, lo and behold, this issue is resolved after re-opening Chrome!